# random image order using Orbit slider

Tags: jquery, orbit

I'm using the Orbit slider and would like to have the first image dispalyed to be randomly selected from my image collection rather than the specified order in the code.

Below is the link to the slider and my code. http://zurb.com/playground/orbit-jquery-image-slider

### jQuery

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('#featured').orbit();
});
```

### HTML

```
<div id="featured">
    <a href="1.php" data-caption="#htmlCaption1" target="_parent">
        <img    src="/images/image1.jpg"   border="0" />
    </a>
    <a href="2.php" data-caption="#htmlCaption2" target="_parent">
        <img src="/images/image1.jpg"  border="0" />
    </a>
    <a href="3.php" data-caption="#htmlCaption3" target="_parent">
        <img src="/images/image1.jpg" border="0"/>
    </a>
</div>
<span class="orbit-caption" id="htmlCaption1"> Text here.</span>
<span class="orbit-caption" id="htmlCaption2"> Text here.</span>
<span class="orbit-caption" id="htmlCaption3"> Text here.</span>
```

Comment: I've been woodworking all day and misread the title as `... using orbital sander`.

Answer (score 0):

If orbit doesn't have a random-start option, then try pre-processing the list of images before invoking `orbit()` on it.

Something like this should do it :

```
var $container = $("#featured");
var n = $container.find("a").length;
var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * n) + 1);
for(var i=0; i<rand; i++) {
    $container.find("a").eq(0);
}
$container.orbit();
```